# Reading txt file from Internal storage returns FIleNotFound even file is present at the address

Tags: android, file-handling, internal-storage

i am trying to read file from internal storage. the file is available in internal storage at given location and the code is able to access it.. but when it tries to open the file , it throws FileNotFound Exception which is due to **the app can't open the file to read**. I came to know about **the app can't open the file** by using `file.canRead()` method which is returning false. can anybody help me to figure the situation out? Here is my code

```
path = MainActivity.this.getFilesDir().getAbsolutePath();
try {
        File file = new File(path, "jamshaid.txt");
        Context ctx = getApplicationContext();
        FileInputStream fileInputStream = ctx.openFileInput(file.getName());
        InputStreamReader inputStreamReader = new InputStreamReader(fileInputStream);
        BufferedReader bufferedReader = new BufferedReader(inputStreamReader);
        String lineData = bufferedReader.readLine();
        view1.setText(lineData);

    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
```

## Permissions

`<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET"/>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE"/>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE"/>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE"/>`

> API Version of my device is 24

## What i wanna do?

i am trying to parsethe file/set text file data to textView

## Update1

after changing
            `File directory = MainActivity.this.getFilesDir();
            File file = new File(directory, "jamshaid.txt");`
i am getting the following error

```
`09-25 14:45:16.413 21144-21144/com.example.root.testingvolley     W/System.err: java.io.FileNotFoundException: /data/user/0/com.example.root.testingvolley/files/jamshaid.txt (No such file or directory)`
```

Comment: Make sure that you checked permission(read, write, ...) to work with File

Comment: @MiladBahmanabadi i have added the permissions i have in my manifest to the question. please have a look

Comment: @Nancy, would you mention your device api version?

Comment: @MohammodHossain api version is 24

Comment: @Nancy yes now you added permissions...

Comment: @MiladBahmanabadi these were in the manifest already. i just added them in the question

Comment: You don't need permissions to read from the app internal storage! [Documentation](https://developer.android.com/training/data-storage/files#WriteInternalStorage)

Comment: @LonelyC i am also storing files after downloading them to the internal storage. that's why i am using that

Answer (score 1):

**Try this for directory path**

```
File directory = context.getFilesDir();
File file = new File(directory, filename);
```

Or

```
public String getTextFileData(String fileName) {

        StringBuilder text = new StringBuilder();


        try {


         FileInputStream fIS = getApplicationContext().openFileInput(fileName);
         InputStreamReader isr = new InputStreamReader(fIS, "UTF-8");
         BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(isr);

            String line;

            while ((line = br.readLine()) != null) {
                text.append(line + '\n');
            }
            br.close();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            Log.e("Error!", "Error occured while reading text file from Internal Storage!");

        }

        return text.toString();

    }
```

Comment: i have added stacktrace. please have a look

Answer (score 0):

How are you verifying that the file exists? Perhaps the file does not exist, in which case openFileInput() will throw FileNotFoundException.

You can try opening the file in write-mode which will create a file if no such file exists.

```
FileOutputStream fileOutputStream = ctx.openFileOutput(file.getName(), ctx.MODE_PRIVATE);
```

Comment: the file already exists at the given path. it's downloaded and stored the from firebase storage

Comment: @MohammodHossain what do you mean. i am just trying to read it... how can it be written at the same time?